# PHP - can't access array values

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to access a MySQL database with PHP, but I am running into a problem with the data.  On my development machine (PHP version 5.5), this code works perfectly, but on the production server (PHP version 5.6), the code seems to be failing when dealing with an array.  Basically, I seem to get the code below to `echo` that `$parks` is indeed an array, and adding

```
foreach ($parks as $key => $val) {
    echo $key;
};
```

will correctly echo the array keys, but if I swap out `echo $key` for `echo $val`, nothing happens, no echo at all.

```
<?php
    $dbname = "DATABASE";
    $password = "PASSWORD";
    $servername = "localhost";
    $dbname = "NAME";

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    $query = "SELECT name, latitude, longitude, description, where_to_go from locations";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    $parks = [];

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){                   
        $park = new stdClass();
        $location = new stdClass();
        $location->lat = floatval($row['latitude']);
        $location->lng = floatval($row['longitude']);
        $park->title = $row['name'];
        $park->location = $location;
        $park->description = $row['description'];
        $park->whereToGo = $row['where_to_go'];
        array_push($parks, json_encode($park));
    };
    /*
    foreach ($parks as $key => $val) {
        echo $key; //THIS WILL WORK
    };

    foreach ($parks as $key => $val) {
        echo $val; //THIS WILL NOT RETURN ANYTHING
    };

    echo $parks[0] //SIMILARLY, THIS WILL NOT RETURN ANYTHING
    */

    $conn->close();
?>
```

To further illustrate the point, the next step in my program is to get the `$parks` array into a JavaScript variable...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var locations = <?php echo json_encode($parks); ?>;
    var locations = locations.map(JSON.parse);
    console.log(locations);
</script>
```

And running all of this will log `[false]`.

To test things, I threw a few `echo`s into the `while` loop in the PHP for the different attributes of `$park` and they output the correct values... so the array seems to be built correctly, but I can't seem to get anything out of it.

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: Do a `var_dump($parks);` please

Comment: May be `json_encode` is not working. Try to make `var_dump(json_encode($park))` just before `array_push`

Comment: [json-encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) will return `false` on failure. That's why you have valid keys but all values are setup to `false` in `$parks` variable

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie `var_dump($parks)` returns `array(1) { [0]=> bool(false) }`

Comment: @luchaninov that returns `bool(false)`.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be a problem with `json_encode`...

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: @skwidbreth - first of all ensure that you have this function. Try `var_dump(json_encode('test'))`. If it's not working, install it using something like `apt-get install php5-json; service php5-fpm restart; service apache2 restart;` or turn on some checkbox in your hosting control panel. If function is working then look closely to the object you want to encode: `var_dump($park);`.

Comment: Thank you all for helping me - it looks like this is a problem with `encode_json`.   I will try to implement luchaninov's solution.

Comment: I doubt it. your `echo $val;` in loop would not work as you are trying to echo an object, and that wont work unless you have a tostring method

Comment: Thanks all - I was trying to deploy this on someone else's server and it would not run - the problem was definitely with `encode_json`, because I ran it on a server that I maintain and it worked perfectly.  Literally the same code... the first server kept choking on that...

Answer (score 0):

Try this please:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){                   
    $park = new stdClass();
    $location = new stdClass();
    $location->lat = floatval($row['latitude']);
    $location->lng = floatval($row['longitude']);
    $park->title = $row['name'];
    $park->location = $location;
    $park->description = $row['description'];
    $park->whereToGo = $row['where_to_go'];
    $parks[] = json_encode(get_object_vars($park));
};
```

Or just use arrays:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){                   
    $park = [];
    $location = [];
    $location['lat'] = floatval($row['latitude']);
    $location['lng'] = floatval($row['longitude']);
    $park['title'] = $row['name'];
    $park['location'] = $location;
    $park['description'] = $row['description'];
    $park['whereToGo'] = $row['where_to_go'];
    $parks[] = json_encode($park);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Odd, but maybe try to create your own virtual Index...

```
$c = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){                   
    $park = new stdClass();
    $location = new stdClass();
    $location->lat = floatval($row['latitude']);
    $location->lng = floatval($row['longitude']);
    $park->title = $row['name'];
    $park->location = $location;
    $park->description = $row['description'];
    $park->whereToGo = $row['where_to_go'];
    $parks[$c] = json_encode($park);
    $c++;
};
```

The problem might be linked that objects cannot be array-keys. I mean in general it should create a numerical key but maybe its an issue between PHP 5.5 and 5.6 as you mentioned.

Try this way should ensure you have a numerical array that can be foreached easily.

Answer (score 0):

Your probelm is that you are ( I assume ) trying to create an array of objects, but in fact you are overwriting the array each time round the loop

This will create an array of object from your rows

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$query = "SELECT name, latitude, longitude, description, where_to_go from locations";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

$parks = [];

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){                   
    $t = new stdClass();

    $t->title = $row['name'];
    $t->location = $location;
    $t->description = $row['description'];
    $t->whereToGo = $row['where_to_go'];

    $l = new stdClass();
    $l->lat = floatval($row['latitude']);
    $l->lng = floatval($row['longitude']);

    $t->location = $l;

    $parks[] = $t
}
$jsonString = json_encode($parks);
```

Now you can do whatever you like with the `$jsonString` or fiddle with the  `$parks` array

```
print_r($parks);
```

Comment: Thank you - I'll try this and see if it works, but I don't think that's the issue... again, my script worked perfectly on my development machine (and my own server, which I later tried deploying this on).